# Why we use "this" keyword in this case?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code from a certain course, and its goal is that after clicking on a specific `<p>` element, the edit class is deleted on all the elements that own this class, and then it adds the edit class to the `<p>` element that was clicked.

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");

elements.forEach(function (ele) {

    ele.onclick = function () {
        elements.forEach(function (ele) {
            ele.classList.remove("edit");
        })
    
        this.classList.add("edit");
    }
})
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Mustapha</p>
    <p>Ali</p>
    <p>Osama</p>
    <p>Hamza</p>
</body>
```

This code works perfectly fine, but the thing I want to make sure of is why the course owner used the keyword `this` to add the class edit to the element that was clicked instead of using only the ele parameter. I tried using the parameter ele instead of the `this` keyword and noticed that the code worked fine.

Comment: `event.target` will do the same. I Think it's up to you what you choose.

Comment: _"why is it used here"_ - Ask the author why he/she choose to use `ele` and not any of the other possibilities like `this`.

Answer (score 1):

For a handler method the [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) handled is the parameter. Within such a handler method `this` will be the <strike>global</strike> *scope the handler is defined within* (e.g. `button.onclick` => the button clicked). <strike>, i.e. `window`</strike>.

Note that the scope for a handler method that is an *arrow function* will always be `window`.

Furthermore, there is no need for a handler method attached to every `p` element. Try using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation), for example:

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains(`canEdit`)) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.canEdit`).forEach( el => 
      el.classList.remove(`edit`) );
    evt.target.classList.add(`edit`);
  }
}
```

```css
.edit {
  color: red;
}

p.canEdit {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p class="canEdit">Mustapha</p>
<p class="canEdit">Ali</p>
<p class="canEdit">Osama</p>
<p class="canEdit">Hamza</p>
<p>Abdel</p>
```

Comment: Would use toggle instead -> `evt.target.classList.toggle('edit');`

Comment: Yep, maybe. But reading OP's code more closely I don't think that's the intention of it. Edited the code in the answer accordingly.

Comment: _"Within such a handler method `this` will be the global scope, i.e. `window`."_ - That's not true: https://jsfiddle.net/q4cm526s/

Comment: @Andreas You're right. Edited the answer.  And [see also](https://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/bqo0d8nc/)